# Python Pandas "<" operator against "<=" error

Tags: python, pandas

I'm targeting to find provisional minimums in a dataframe. To find them I search values that are lower than the minimum of the previous 3 values in a dataframe colum. Tested in Google Colab and python 3.9 in windows.

Maybe there is other more *Pandastic* way of doing this.

The problem: when using `<=` everything seems to work fine, but when using `<`, nothing was found. Even when the provided data should be matched.

```
import pandas as pd    
data_list = [55,66,77,88,99,88,77,66,55,54,65,67,68,70,73,78,83]  # use any other values
low = pd.Series(data_list)
df = pd.DataFrame(low.values, columns=['Low'])
df
        Low
    0   55
    1   66
    2   77
    3   88
    4   99
    5   88
    6   77
    7   66
    8   55
...

df.plot(grid=True)
```

[image]

When trying to find values lower than the 3 previos rows **OR EQUAL**, everything works fine:

```
df[df['Low'] <= df['Low'].rolling(3).min()]

Low
5   88
6   77
7   66
8   55
9   54
```

**The Problem**: But when using just **<** operator, nothing was found.

```
df[df['Low'] < df['Low'].rolling(3).min()]
```

This are the versions used in google colab (python 3.7), updated:

```
!pip install numpy --upgrade
!pip install pandas --upgrade
!pip freeze ...
numpy==1.21.5
pandas==1.3.5
```

When using local Python 3.9, same behaviour.

Comment: the behavior is expected given the data you have provided, only `<=` works because when it returns `True` for those rows they are in fact `==`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*trying to find values lower than the 3 previos rows*

When you do `df[df['Low'] <= df['Low'].rolling(3).min()]` or `df[df['Low'] < df['Low'].rolling(3).min()]` you are not comparing to *3 previous rows* but current row and 2 previous.

You need to [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) if you want to get desired behavior that is

```
import pandas as pd    
data_list = [55,66,77,88,99,88,77,66,55,54,65,67,68,70,73,78,83]  # use any other values
low = pd.Series(data_list)
df = pd.DataFrame(low.values, columns=['Low'])
print(df[df['Low'] < df['Low'].rolling(3).min().shift()])
```

output

```
   Low
6   77
7   66
8   55
9   54
```